# webform with built in paypal donate button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, paypal, donations

Is it possible to have a paypal donation button within a webform with radio buttons so the person has to donate to send the form? If so, how could this be achieved?

Thanks in advance

```
text-decoration: none}
.robolink:link {font-weight: bold; font-size: 9pt; color: #999999; font-family: Arial,     Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: none}
.robolink:hover {font-weight: bold; font-size: 9pt; color: #979653; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: underline}
 .robolink:visited {font-weight: bold; font-size: 9pt; color: #979653; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: none}
</style>
 <form name="htmlphpformgenerator1" method="Post" action="mailto:davidbackward@me.com">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td valign=top>What Snake?</td><td valign=top>
<input type="radio" name="What_Snake__1" value="Retic" checked>Retic<br>
<input type="radio" name="What_Snake__1" value="Boa">Boa<br>
<input type="radio" name="What_Snake__1" value="Grass">Grass<br>
<input type="radio" name="What_Snake__1" value="King">King<br>
<input type="radio" name="What_Snake__1" value="Cobra">Cobra<br>
 </td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Cast Your Vote"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2 class=robotext><a href="http://www.phpform.info" class="robolink">HTML/PHP Form Generator</a> from ROBO Design Solutions</td></tr></table></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to design the donation button to be the submit button (which can be done through your paypal account). Here are the instructions for doing so:

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_donate-intro-outside

You may want to make it clear to the end user that by clicking submit, they will be redirected to PayPal for a donation.

Hope this helps.